# Añadir elemento nuevo a lista

Tags: c, lista, estructuras

Tengo un problema a la hora de añadir un elemento a una lista al final de la lista .
La función que tengo es:

```
void aniadir(struct Lista *lista){
  struct Alumno aux;
  printf("Escribe numero matricula, nombre, apellidos y nota del alumnos");
  scanf("%d %s %s %d", &aux.Matricula, &aux.Nombre, &aux.Apellidos, &aux.Nota);
  lista->Datos[lista->Numero]=aux;
  lista->Numero++;
  //Estos printf son solo para comprobar
  printf("\n %d %s %s %d", aux.Matricula, aux.Nombre, aux.Apellidos, aux.Nota);
  printf("\n %d %s %s %d", lista->Datos[lista->Número].Matricula, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nombre, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Apellidos, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nota);
}
```

También he probado a:

```
lista->Datos[lista->Número].Matricula=aux.Matricula;
lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nombre=aux.Nombre;
lista->Datos[lista->Número].Apellidos=aux.Apellidos;
lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nota=aux.Nota;
```

En vez de:

```
lista->Datos[lista->Número]=aux;
```

No me aparecen errores.
Cuando ejecuto el programa e intento añadir a *457 Marcos FernandezGarcia 8*

El resultado es:

*457 Marcos FernandezGarcia 8*

*273738382882 @ Pwk 2893*

Por lo tanto el alumno si está guardado en aux pero no soy capaz de meterlo en la lista

Las estructuras son:

```
typedef char Cadena [MAX]
struct Alumno{
  int Matricula;
  Cadena Nombre;
  Cadena Apellidos;
  int Nota;
};

struct Lista{
  int Numero;
  struct Alumno Datos[MAXC];
};
// MAX está declarado al principio con valor 40
// MAXC está declarado al principio con valor 30
```

Estoy trabajando en Code::Blocks

Main:

```
int main(){
  struct Lista lista;
  FILE *f;
  lista.Numero=0;
  int n;
  meterEnLista(&lista) //Esta función mete los datos del fichero en la lista
  do{
    printf("Seleccione la operacion \n1.Mostrar Lista\n2.Añadir Alumno\n3.Guardar Lista\n0. Salir");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    switch(n){
      case 1:
        mostrarLista(&lista); //Recorre la lista. Funciona perfectamente
        break;
      case 2:
        aniadir(&lista); 
        break;
      case 3:
        fichero=fopen("Clase.txt","w");
        guardarLista(&lista,f); //Guarda en el fichero la lista. Funciona perfectamente
        break;
  }    
  while( n!=0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código tiene varios errores:

**1.-** El miembro `Datos` no es un *array* de estructuras, por lo tanto, es ilegal escribir una sentencia así:

```c
lista->Datos[lista->Número]=aux;
```

**2.-** El tipo del miembro `Datos` no puede ser `Lista`, de lo contrario, no podrás tener acceso a los miembros de la estructura `Alumno`.

La estructura `Lista` debería estar definida de esta forma:

```c
struct Lista
{
  int Número;
  struct Alumno Datos[50];
};
```

**3.-** En la función `scanf` debes pasar la dirección de memoria de la variable y no su *contenido*:

```c
scanf("%d", n);
```

Esto provoca un fallo de segmentación, ya que la función estaría accediendo a memoria que no le pertenece al programa.

**Solución:**

```c
//El ampersand se usa para pasar la dirección de memoria de "n".
scanf("%d", &n);
```

**4.-** Estás incrementando el miembro `Numero` antes de mostrar la información:

```c
lista->Datos[lista->Numero]=aux;
lista->Numero++;
//Estos printf son solo para comprobar
printf("\n %d %s %s %d", aux.Matricula, aux.Nombre, aux.Apellidos, aux.Nota);
printf("\n %d %s %s %d", lista->Datos[lista->Número].Matricula, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nombre, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Apellidos, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nota);
```

Al principio `Numero` vale `0` pero luego lo incrementas a `1` y recién ahí muestras la información, sin embargo, imprimirá contenido basura, porque la información está en la posición anterior (en este caso en la posición `0`).

**Solución:** Debes incrementar el miembro `Numero` al final:

```c
lista->Datos[lista->Numero]=aux;
//Estos printf son solo para comprobar
printf("\n %d %s %s %d", aux.Matricula, aux.Nombre, aux.Apellidos, aux.Nota);
printf("\n %d %s %s %d", lista->Datos[lista->Número].Matricula, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nombre, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Apellidos, lista->Datos[lista->Número].Nota);
lista->Numero++;
```

**Recomendación:**

Deberías de añadir una condición en la función `aniadir` para que no sobrepase el límite del *array* (en este caso es `50`).

Comment: Cierto, solucione el error al poco de copiarlo aquí pero aún así sigue sin funcionar. El error 1 no se como corregirlo o si con el 2 ya se soluciona. Gracias por ayudarme, se me olvido añadir esos cambios

Comment: @Layu ¿Por qué usas el miembro `Num` en vez de `Número`? Debes usar el miembro que esté declarado en la estructura `Lista` (en este caso es `Número`). Debes decidir que *nombre* usar. Ahora, necesito que agregues en la pregunta la forma como invocas la función `aniadir ` en el `main`. Porque a simple vista no veo ningún error en tu código. Por cierto, ¿qué IDE estás usando y en que sistema operativo estás compilando?

Comment: Estoy usando Code::Blocks, el compilador es GNU GCC Compiler, en Windows 10

Comment: @Layu Edité la respuesta. Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

tu problema está en la definición de tipos, lo correcto sería asi:

```
struct Alumno 
{
   int    Matricula;
   Cadena Nombre;
   Cadena Apellidos;
   int    Nota;
};

struct Lista 
{
   int          Numero;
   struct Alumno Datos[20];
};
```

La estructura Lista está compuesta por Numero que contendrá el número de elementos dentro de la lista y los Datos que será en el caso de arriba un array de 20 elemntos de tipo Alumno. En tu código pones struct Lista Datos; y es ahí donde radica el problema que estás declarando otro tipo Lista pero nada que ver con la estructura Alumno.

Para que funcione ya sólo basta con llamar a cada cosa como es:

```
void aniadir(struct Lista *lista)
{
    struct Alumno aux;
    printf("Escribe numero matricula, nombre, apellidos y nota del alumnos");
    scanf("%d %s %s %d", &aux.Matricula, &aux.Nombre, &aux.Apellidos, &aux.Nota);
    // Se añade a la lista
    lista->Datos[lista->Numero]=aux;
    
    //Estos printf son solo para comprobar
    //
    // OJO! en tu código usas ->Número para acceder en lugar de ->Numero
    //      aquí ya va corregido.
    // 
    printf("\n %d %s %s %d", aux.Matricula, aux.Nombre, aux.Apellidos, aux.Nota);
    printf("\n %d %s %s %d", lista->Datos[lista->Numero].Matricula, lista->Datos[lista->Numero].Nombre, lista->Datos[lista->Numero].Apellidos, lista->Datos[lista->Numero].Nota);
    // Contempla el elemento añadido incrementando el contador.
    lista->Numero++;  
}
```

Comment: Cierto, lo cambie pero se me olvido modificar aquí eso, aún cambiando eso sigue sin funcionar. Lo cambie y sigue mostrando lo mismo por pantalla. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: He extendido la respuesta con código, espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!